# Bootstrap search box is not visible when window is resized

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have created a simple web page using bootstrap classes. I created a header, in normal window view, it shows the search box.

When I resize the window or text in mobile devices, the search box is not shown.

What am I missing?

Here is my coding:

```
<header class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top bs-docs-nav" role="banner">
<div class="container">
<div class="navbar-header">
<button class="navbar-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="bs-navbar-collapse">
<span class="sr-only">Toggle Navigation</span>
<span class="icon-bar"></span>
<span class="icon-bar"></span>
<span class="icon-bar"></span>
</button>
<a href="index.html" class="navbar-brand">Aerospace</a>
</div>
<nav class="collapse navbar-collapse bs-navbar-collapse" role="navigation">
<form class="navbar-form navbar-right" role="search">
<div class="form-group">
<input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="search">
</div>
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-deafult">Submit</button>
</form>
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
<li class="active"><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
<li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
<li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
</ul>
</nav>
</div>
</header>
```

Any advice would be useful for me.

Thanks,

Comment: A fiddle about this would be useful.

Comment: probably your search box is setted to be "display:none" under a certain size.
Could you please provide your css

Comment: manual css is called blog.css.. it has only body {margin-top:75px;} thats it.. all others are bootstrap CDN only..

Comment: its container `<nav>` is set as `display:hidden` by bootstrap

Comment: may i know, why i has set display:hidden; ..? thanks

Comment: The searchbox is there http://jsfiddle.net/k531yft3/5/ . You have a problem with the menu on mobile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is here

```
<button class="navbar-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="bs-navbar-collapse">
```

here `data-target="bs-navbar-collapse"` it should be `data-target=".bs-navbar-collapse"`

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/740re0ch/)

Comment: did you put `.` because data-target is this `<nav class="collapse navbar-collapse bs-navbar-collapse" role="navigation">` and it's a class `bs-navbar-collapse`

Comment: If it's working here http://jsfiddle.net/740re0ch/1/ should be working in your code because I didn't change anything else in your code

Answer (score 0):

This is how it should be done:

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar"> <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>

      </button> <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html">Aerospace</a>

    </div>
    <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
      <form class="navbar-form navbar-right" role="search">
        <div class="form-group">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="search" />
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-deafult">Submit</button>
      </form>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="index.html">Home</a>

        </li>
        <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a>

        </li>
        <li><a href="about.html">About</a>

        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <!--/.navbar-collapse -->
  </div>
</nav>
```

The markup is just wrong. If you have more questions, comment.

Answer (score 0):

Check this out it works fine..

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Bootstrap, from Twitter</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <meta name="description" content="" />
    <meta name="author" content="" />
    <!-- Le styles -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" />

    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>

    <header class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top bs-docs-nav" role="banner">
      <div class="container">
          <div class="navbar-header">
               <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" 
           data-target=".bs-navbar-collapse">
                  <span class="sr-only">Toggle Navigation</span>
                  <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                  <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                  <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              </button>
              <a href="index.html" class="navbar-brand">Aerospace</a>
          </div>
          <nav class="collapse navbar-collapse bs-navbar-collapse" role="navigation">
              <form class="navbar-form navbar-right" role="search">
                  <div class="form-group">
                      <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="search">
                  </div>
                  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-deafult">Submit</button>
              </form>
              <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                  <li class="active"><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
                  <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
                  <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
              </ul>
          </nav>
      </div>
  </header>


    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The code is correct, the search bar is hidden from mobile device, click on the right button to show all hidden elements from mobile.

Note: Have you included jQuery and bootstrap js libraries?
If you cannot see the hidden data clicking in the right button (hamburger button) from mobile, include the above below libraries

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```